# Is there a list of closed sites?

Tags: support, area-51, closed-sites

Is there a way to list all the closed sites (Atheism, How Things Work etc) on Area 51?

Comment: I think this question is obviously on-topic for the 'Meta' site. This question should be re-opened though it is properly answered.

Answer (score 6):

**No, there isn't.**

Currently, you can only view proposals which have been closed, via:

[`http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3a1`](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3a1)

But NullUserException has already suggested a [search option for launched and closed proposals](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3818/34386) over in the Area 51 discussion.

Comment: aaaaand that's how I found out that [the Magic: the Gathering proposal was just closed](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/why-is-the-magic-the-gathering-proposal-shutting-down).

Comment: Damn, they have to fix links in code.